# Ошибка message_handler: Commands filter should be list of strings

Tags: python, telebot

Сама ошибка:

> ERROR - TeleBot: "message_handler: Commands filter should be list of
> strings (commands), unknown type supplied to the 'commands' filter
> list. Not able to use the supplied type."

Она происходит после того, как вводится название товара.

В чём заключается проблема, если я передаю команды как список? Работоспособность функции get_data проверил, в ней точно нет проблем.

Код:

```
import config
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button_A = telebot.types.KeyboardButton("Найти магазин с наименьшей ценой на товар")
    markup.row(button_A)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, config.greetings,reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Найти магазин с наименьшей ценой на товар')
def request_name_of_product(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите название товара")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def result(message):
    name = message.text
    data = get_data_magnit(name)
    for name,prices in data.items():
        s = f"Название продукта: {name}\nЦена без скидки: {prices['old_price']}\nЦена со скидкой: {prices['new_price']}" if type(prices) != str else prices
        bot.message_handler(message.chat.id,s)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: что должна делать команда `bot.message_handler(message.chat.id,s)`?

Comment: По моей задумке она должна высылать цену на товар, который раньше ввёл пользователь или сообщать об отсутсвтии скидок на него

Comment: так для отправки используйте `bot.send_message`